# Flutter - How set all my data (fields) from firebase documents to table

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all user data fields from documents to table to compare users scores live.

This is my Firestore document:

[image]

right now the only thing I success to get is only the Collection Id and the documents files name(the uuid).
any idea how to get user data fields?

this is what I've built for now:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../welcome/welcome_screen.dart';

class Records extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecordsState createState() => _RecordsState();
}

@override
class _RecordsState extends State<Records> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(" טבלת שיאים לשאלון מספר - " + IDController.text)),
        body: new Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            new Image(
              image: AssetImage(
                "assets/background/zooc.jpg",
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
            new StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection(IDController.text)
                  .orderBy('studentScore', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
                if (snapshot.hasData) return new Text('המערכת טוענת נתונים...');
                return new DataTable(
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    new DataColumn(label: Text('studentName')),
                    new DataColumn(label: Text('studentScore')),
                    new DataColumn(label: Text('endTime')),
                  ],
                  rows: _createRows(snapshot.data),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List _createRows(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    List newList = snapshot.docs.map(
      (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        return new DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(Text(documentSnapshot['studentName'].toString())),
            DataCell(Text(documentSnapshot['studentScore'].toString())),
            DataCell(Text(documentSnapshot['endTime'].toString())),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).toList();
    return newList;
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Kobi

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is using multiple "orderby" which are not allowed. Try with any one like -

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection(IDController.text)
                  .orderBy('studentScore', descending: true)
                  .snapshots()
```

Or if you want to sort by all then perform the sorting separately after receiving the data.

Hope it helps....